# When using Excelwriter in a loop, it retains worksheets from prior loops

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, pandas.excelwriter

I'm trying to create multiple Excel spreadsheets from a list of dataframes. Each excel spreadsheet is based on a already existing Excel file and I then insert a dataframe and pivot tables as new sheets. Each Excel spreadsheet has a name generated based on data from the dataframe.

The code roughly looks like

```
wb = load_workbook('baseline excel file.xlsx')

for df in quad_df_list:
    remediated_df = remdiation_function(df)
    remediated_pt = remediated_df.pivot_table(yadda yadda)

    #the month and year are the same in each dataframe
    #source is the only value that's different
    source = remediated_df['Source_ID'].value_counts().index[0]

    output_name = 'remediation workbook {month} {year} {source}'.format(month = month, year = year, source = source}
    #eg output_name = remediation workbook june 2021 A

    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_name, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        #insert the base excel sheet
        writer.book = wb

        remediated_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='remediated data')
        remediated_pt.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='remediated pivot table')
```

What ends up happening is that each iteration contains the dataframe and pivot table worksheets that were inserted in the prior iterations. As if writer is working on the same file each iteration. And i have no idea why or how to "empty out" each instance of ExcelWriter in each loop.

Comment: The docs say "The writer should be used as a context manager." so it seems reasonable to use it this way. Any chance your remediation_function() or writer.book assignment is actually causing the problem?

Comment: The dataframes and pivot tables are all correct in each worksheet, so I don't think it is the function. It could be writer.book assignment, though wb is declared outside the loop so adding it to writer doesn't seem like it should add anything else, but I haven't found much about ExcelWriter.book so I could be wrong.

Comment: it was the writer.book assignment. i commented it out and it created each file without including any preceding sheets from previous iterations. I guess now I need to figure out extracting each sheet from the loaded workbook and inserting them into the new ExcelWriter.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing the naming convention for files (generally, spaces in file names are a real headache). <s>Looking at the docs for ExcelWriter, the default mode is write, whereas I think you would like append to not overwrite the document.</s>

Comment: It's supposed to be a new document each time. Source_ID will be unique to each dataframe, so it is creating a new file each iteration and with the correct filename.